# jQuery this() loop issues

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate clouds across a page with jQuery, and move them to the end of the page once they go off the far left.

```
<div class="sprite cloud" id="cloud-1"> </div>
```

```
$(function () {
   function runIt() {

   $(".cloud").each(function(){

       var speed = 20;
       var Position = this.position().left;
       var Width =  this.width();
       if((Position + Width) < 0) 
       {
           Position = $(document).width();
           this.css("left", Position);
       }

   });

  $('#clouds').animate({"left": Position-speed},1000, "linear", runIt)}
   runIt();
});
```

It works if I use $('#cloud-1'), etc, but not if I try to use each(). I get an error that says

> Object # has no method 'position'

I get the same error for any function, such as offset().

$(this) instead of this resolved it.

New code:

```
$(function () {
   function runIt() {

   $(".cloud").each(function(){

   var speed = 20;
   var cloudPosition = $(this).position().left;
   var cloudWidth =  $(this).width();

   if((cloudPosition + cloudWidth) < 0) 
   {
       cloudPosition = $(document).width();
       $(this).css("left", cloudPosition);
   }

    $(this).animate({"left": cloudPosition-speed},1000, "linear", runIt)

    });


}

  setInterval(runIt, 1000)
});
```

It only animates once now. I assume it's because the runIt callback is now inside a loop. I tried moving it outside the loop, but that didn't work. Using setInterval works ok, though probably isn't the *proper* way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.position` is a method on jQuery objects, and `this` inside `each` is a DOM Object.

You need to use `$(this).position`

And the same for `width` and `css`

Comment: That was more or less it! It won't loop anymore though, it did with only one. Any ideas?

Comment: @EPICWebDesign, could you post the complete code?

Comment: It's there. This is the test site: http://dev.napkinworks.ca/snowislandedu/